# Angular Material Tab Component - How to change label font size

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using the Angular Material tabs component.  Using an example straight from the official docs...

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Everything works fine except that the font size in the tab labels is smaller than I would like and I can't seem to figure out how to make it bigger.  I've tried multiple things in CSS but clearly I'm missing something.  If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in styles.css
(Correct by @Marshal)

```
.mat-tab-label{
    font-size: 10px !important;
 }
```

Or you can use the following in component CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label .mat-tab-label-content {
    font-size: x-large;
}
```

In CSS we can declare style rules like! Important to make the priority on style rules that can be found before

**EDITED 2021**

Is better use ViewEncapsulation

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
// ...
@Component({
    // ...
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

and in the .scss file.

```
.content { 
   .mat-tab-label{
     font-size: 10px;
   } 
}
```

Be careful, as Angular Material says:

> Turn view encapsulation off on your component. If you do this, be sure
> to scope your styles appropriately, or else you may end up
> incidentally targeting other components elsewhere in your application.

https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

Comment: You have a syntax error in your provided code, `!important` alone is not a functional example in this case, unless added to the root style.css which was not specified... this is the reason I provided my answer along with working stackblitz example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  I gave this a try and it didn't seem to make a different in the size of the label unfortunately.  I've included a stackblitz link so you can see the behavior.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y66rll?embed=1&file=app/tab-group-basic-example.css

Comment: true @Marshal, I wanted to say that I added it in style.css. 
apologies for the mistake

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks so much to both of you for taking the time to share your knowledge.  I don't have enough rep to upvote yet but I tried just the same. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To change the tab label font, in global *styles.scss*

```
div .mat-mdc-tab {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```