# Angular Material Tab - How to change label font size

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I was wondering what the best way to change the label font is. There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286721/angular-material-tab-component-how-to-change-label-font-size), however one answer said to add to styles.css file (which works) but that seems inefficient and I would like to avoid that if possible. Also, since `::ng-deep` has been deprecated, is there a replacement that would work for this situation?
Thanks in advance!

```html
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: NG-deep still seems a valid way to do that. Search "ng-deep alternative" on Google you'll have an interesting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would deffinitely suggest sticking with `::ng-deep` but use it with `:host` (if you want to prevent the style bleeding into other components).

```css
:host /deep/ .whateverClass {
//...
}
```

However, if you are changing some prefabricated style like Material, you could also want to preservate uniformity thus you should use the `::ng-deep` in the topmost component without the `:host` selector.